# Почему cURL запросы из одного скрипта выполняются быстрее чем из нескольких?

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

У меня есть php скрипт который с помощью multi-curl делает по 10 запросов в цикле к моему удаленному серверу.

Если я запускаю только 1 экземпляр этого php скрипта, то он за час получает 10тыс результатов.

Но если я запускаю например 20 экземпляров этого php скрипта, я ожидаю за час получить 20*10 =  200тыс результатов, а получаю около 100тыс.

Важно заметить, что каждый экземпляр скрипта делает запрос к разным серверам (не повторяются), это мои сервера и там установлено абсолютно одинаковая ОС и они выполняют одинаковые операции, они в точности скопированы.

Я протестировал каждый свой удаленный сервер по отдельности, они дают 10тыс (+- парочка) результатов за час.

Может быть на сервере с которого я отправляю cURL запросы есть какие-то ограничения пропускной способности сети? как это выяснить?

ОС Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: один скрипт использует доступные ресурсы или несколько, есть же разница? И с точки зрения сети, это такое же подключение, у которого есть пропускная способность, которая будет разделяться между разными скриптами.

Comment: @Дмитрий как определить каких ресурсов скрипты не хватает? взял мощный сервер, скрипт оптимизирован по максимуму.

Comment: Вы можете наблюдать за утилизацией серверов в онлайне? Если да, то запустите 20 потоков и смотрите, где что проседает. Так же, если скрипт один с одной логикой, то вызов 20 одновременно приведет к тому, что по вашему алгоритму будут оправшиваться сразу 20 ресурсов одновременно и подозреваю одинаковых. Может вы CPU или RAM упираетесь в какие то моменты. Если есть БД, то она тоже может давать свои накладные расходны при вызовах

Comment: @SwaD я пинаю именно на сервер с которого я посылаю cURL, потому что если я запускаю 20 экзеплляров php скрипта который отправлет cURL и ждем ответ, то они за час сделают меньше результатов по сравнению если бы я запустил  по одному такому же php скрипту на разных серверах

Comment: Я сомневаюсь, что у вас на сервере более 20 ядер. Следовательно, 20 активных задач, это как минимум расходы в OS на переключение использования CPU и выделение времени на это. Если есть работа с диском(пишем/читаем что то), то так же дисковой подсистеме приходится обслуживать 20 задач. Поэтому открывайте мониторинг ресурсов сервера, пускайте задачи и смотрите, что у вас твоирится